# How can I record that sound going out of my speakers (not what's coming into the mic)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, mp3, alsa

I'm trying to record the sound my computer produces (without using a microphone)

I've found these two commands that work to record my *microphone* output into files:

```
# creates mp3
arecord -f cd > my_file.mp3

# creates ogg
arecord -f cd -t raw | oggenc - -r -o out.ogg
```

However I am not sure how to record the audio coming out of my speakers directly.

---

I should note that I have figured out how to do this using PulseAudio and Audacity - there's a good tutorial [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229352/how-to-record-output-to-speakers) however it broke my microphone input and also I would like to be able to do it from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revisiting this 5 months later, I finally figured it out.

From the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229352/how-to-record-output-to-speakers):

1. `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-utils lame mpg123`
2. `pacmd list-sinks | grep -e 'name:' -e 'index' -e 'Speakers'`, find the string in between `<>` brackets - for me it's `alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo`
3. start playing some audio
4. `parec -d alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor | lame -r -V0 - out.mp3`
5. control + c to stop

Now for the tricky part, the file for some reason cannot be listened to with `aplay` - it just sounds like static. Listen to it with `mpg123` instead.